# Query for Joining two collection in mongo from one array filed of primary collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have two collections, one is subsegments as below:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "5c8b2931ff2fa8129c8f666f",
    "segments": [
      "5c8b2915ff2fa8129c8f666d"
    ],
    "isSchool": false,
    "isActive": false,
    "isDeleted": true,
    "name": "X-IIT MAINS-1552623928407",
    "bannerUrl": "",
    "timestamp": 1552623921559,
    "updatedAt": "2019-03-15T04:25:28.408Z",
    "createdAt": "2019-03-15T04:25:21.559Z",
    "__v": 0,
    "iconUrl": null,
    "updatedById": null
  }
]
```

Other one is segments as below:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "5a11620dbed7fd0c58ef4ec7",
    "createdAt": "2017-11-19T10:50:53.495Z",
    "updatedAt": "2018-08-27T12:25:36.997Z",
    "timestamp": 1511088653495,
    "bannerUrl": "",
    "iconUrl": "https://bloom-foundation-dev.s3.amazonaws.com/20171129T000000Z_CBSE_Logo-1.jpg",
    "name": "CBSE",
    "isDeleted": false,
    "isActive": true,
    "isSchool": true,
    "__v": 0,
    "updatedById": null
  }
]
```

I want to query to select subsegments and join segments details for various segments ids in the segments array of subsegments

Comment: Maybe this can help https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_mongodb_join.asp

Comment: @Ritesh: What is your expected result? I didn't quite get that from your description :)

Comment: in subsegments there is a segments which is an array of ids for segments. I just want to have fetch segments details using those ids

Comment: Suppose in below lookup query:

{ $lookup:
       {
         from: 'segments',
         localField: 'segments._id',  //it is an array of ids for which i need details from segments
         foreignField: '_id',
         as: 'segmentDetails'
       }
     }